# Not getting all html from website using jsoup

Tags: java, html, web, jsoup

I know that there is a large number of questions of this type but i didn't found an answer...

So the problem is as in Subject. At the beginning webpage requires me to enter a login and password - after log in i'm trying to get whole html but instead of that i have like 10-20% of html and rest of received data is even dont know from where (example below)...

```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> 
> window.currentUserName="******"; 
> window.currentUserGroups={};
> window.currentUserRoles={};
> 
> window.currentUserGroups['InventoryEditor']=true;
> window.currentUserRoles['InventoryEditor']=true;
> window.currentUserGroups['inventoryScriptBypass']=true;
> window.currentUserRoles['User']=true;
> window.currentUserGroups['rsuser']=true;
> window.currentUserRoles['User']=true;
> 
> 
> window.getCurrentUserName = function() {
>     return window.currentUserName; };
> 
> window.currentUserHasGroup = function(groupName) {
>     return window.currentUserGroups[groupName] ? true : false; };
> 
> window.currentUserHasGroups = function(groupNames) {
>     for (var i = 0; i < groupNames.length; i++) {
>         if (window.currentUserHasGroup(groupNames[i])) {
>             return true;
>         }
>     }
>     return false; };
```

and many many more...

My source code below:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("Website before login")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();

Document document = Jsoup.connect("Website after login")
        //.maxBodySize(0)
        //.timeout(0)
        .data("cookieexists", "false")
        .data("login", "login")
        .data("password", "password")
        .data("submit", "Sign in")
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .get();
```

System.out.println(document);
}

When i'm trying to get html from website before login it's working well...
Thanks for your help !

Comment: If the content depends on javascript then jsoup is not enough (no javascript support). If you used the search, you should have read recommendations to use for example HtmlUnit. Without the page url and credentials to login, the question is not reproduce-able.

Comment: Thank you Frederic for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If the content depends on javascript then jsoup is not enough (no javascript support). If you used the search, you should have read recommendations to use for example HtmlUnit. Without the page url and credentials to login, the question is not reproduce-able."